# Why is GCC emitting larger output for a bytewise copy vs memcpy?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, cortex-m

The following C11 program extracts the bit representation of a float into a uint32_t in two different ways.

```
#include <stdint.h>

_Static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t));

uint32_t f2i_char(float f) {
  uint32_t x;
  char const *src = (char const *)&f;
  char *dst = (char *)&x;
  *dst++ = *src++;
  *dst++ = *src++;
  *dst++ = *src++;
  *dst++ = *src++;
  return x;
}

uint32_t f2i_memcpy(float f) {
  uint32_t x;
  memcpy(&x, &f, sizeof(x));
  return x;
}
```

The output assembly, compiled with armgcc 10.2.1 (none eabi) is very different, even with the `-Os` or `-O3` optimizations applied:

I'm compiling with:
`-mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=c11 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard`

```
f2i_char:
  sub sp, sp, #16
  vstr.32 s0, [sp, #4]
  ldr r3, [sp, #4]
  strb r3, [sp, #12]
  ubfx r2, r3, #8, #8
  strb r2, [sp, #13]
  ubfx r2, r3, #16, #8
  ubfx r3, r3, #24, #8
  strb r2, [sp, #14]
  strb r3, [sp, #15]
  ldr r0, [sp, #12]
  add sp, sp, #16
  bx lr
f2i_memcpy:
  sub sp, sp, #8
  vstr.32 s0, [sp, #4]
  ldr r0, [sp, #4]
  add sp, sp, #8
  bx lr
```

Why isn't gcc generating the same assembly for both functions?

[Godbolt example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hcva5sr8x)

Comment: Optimisations are heuristic. Each optimisation level enables a set of specific optimisations, selected because someone thought they are more likely to produce particular results. `-O3`, notably, includes optimisations which may significantly increase compilation time. Some of them, like the one you found here, produce good value for certain programs, but the balance is not so clear.

Comment: It's odd that you do not just use `memcpy`.

Comment: `memcpy` emits assembly identical to the `-O3` version, so I suppose this is another way of asking my question.

Comment: memcpy way does not emit any code as it does not have to do anything. https://godbolt.org/z/q8v39d737 same register for parameter and return value.

Comment: @0___________ OP is compiling for Linux, not for (none). I guess ABI requires different registers. (none) passes floats via r0, Linux passes floats with s0.

Comment: @KamilCuk Cortex M4 does not have linux implemented :). For those micros none EABI is used

Comment: Well, but this would invalidate the question, as the output for `-O3` for (none) is just different.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant to select the none eabi! I'll edit the question and update the link. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @KamilCuk to know the answer for linux-eabi we should know what is included in the particular -Ox options.

Comment: @CharlesNicholson in this case you can simply delete this question as emitted code is exactly the same.,

Comment: ^^ I see one intstruction less, I think, with -O3

Comment: I edited the question for clarity, hopefully this is more precise.

Comment: Your manual naive and useless unrolling [confuses](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/b8j5fKPhT) gcc.

Comment: I found the unrolling clearer + simpler; it wasn't an attempt to outsmart the compiler or optimize anything. Anyway, you should post this as an actual answer since it's a very valuable contribution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104344

GCC does not recognize and match the unrolled version as a bswap or store-merging pattern.

GCC does recognize the loop version.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid manual copy of data. Use `memcpy`. GCC knows this function very well and will not call it at all if not needed. Pointer punning can also break strict-aliasing rules,.

In none-eabi `memcpy` will not emit any code as the return value is passed in the same register as a parameter. No action is needed.

https://godbolt.org/z/q8v39d737

```
#include <stdint.h>

_Static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t));

uint32_t f2i_char(float f) {
  uint32_t x;
  char const *src = (char const *)&f;
  char *dst = (char *)&x;
  *dst++ = *src++;
  *dst++ = *src++;
  *dst++ = *src++;
  *dst++ = *src++;
  return x;
}

uint32_t f2i1(float f) {
  uint32_t x;
  memcpy(&x, &f, sizeof(x));
  return x;
}

f2i_char:
        sub     sp, sp, #8
        ubfx    r1, r0, #8, #8
        ubfx    r2, r0, #16, #8
        ubfx    r3, r0, #24, #8
        strb    r0, [sp, #4]
        strb    r1, [sp, #5]
        strb    r2, [sp, #6]
        strb    r3, [sp, #7]
        ldr     r0, [sp, #4]
        add     sp, sp, #8
        bx      lr
f2i1:
        bx      lr
```

EDIT:

you use `-mfloat-abi=hard` which forces use of the FPU in any float related operations (even not mathematical). usually, I use `softfp` which does hardware floating-point instructions and software floating-point linkage.

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z39qnvY1c

> The output assembly, compiled with armgcc 10.2.1 (none eabi) is very
> different, even with the -Os or -O3 optimizations applied:

Your copy byte by byte and compiler has to follow your code. When you use `memcpy` compiler understands your intention and does not copy byte by byte. Additional float point instructions are needed  because you use `hard` float ABI and ABI forces this operation to be done via the memory (float and int are passed via R0).

Comment: The original code does not violate strict aliasing rules, and the question is not about what I should do but why the compiler emits different code in this specific case.

Comment: @CharlesNicholson see the edit why it does not generate the same code.

Comment: "Your copy byte by byte and the compiler has to follow your code"- Isn't this the point of optimization, though? The compiler is free to emit any instruction stream as long as the result is identically observable. The compiler in this case _could_ know that four sequential writes are the same as a word move; is there any reason that it doesn't do this?

Comment: @CharlesNicholson If you think that it is missed optimization simple fill the bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/. You will get the explained explanation if the GCC team refuses your bug. BTW it is almost always not assigned to anyone even if confirmed (one of the missed optimizations found by me) https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86073

Answer (score 0):

> Why is GCC emitting larger output with -Os than -O3 for this function on Cortex-M4?

Why not? Each option enables or disables specific compiler internal workings. Surely there may be and will be compiler decisions that will make `-O3` result in smaller code than with `-Os`.

> Is there anything specific about the C11 standard or the Armv7E-M that's inhibiting gcc from emitting the smaller assembly at -Os?

No.

> Is this gcc missing an optimization opportunity?

Yes, you could say that. But it may be on purpose - it could be, that the optimization that causes to generate such code is really compilation time and CPU consuming, so it's disabled. It's just that.

Comment: "it could be, that the optimization that causes to generate such code is really compilation time and CPU consuming, so it's disabled"- Are you suggesting that GCC has some sort of runtime performance measurement, and that if compilation time exceeds some threshold, that GCC will fall back to less optimal code?

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting that. I do not know if such thing exists in gcc tests. I would expect it to be arbitrary GCC developer choice based on the experience of a particular developer.

Comment: @CharlesNicholson it is not less optimal code.

Comment: I was just trying to parse what @KamilCuk wrote but I guess it was just a hypothesis.